# Can non-recursively enumerable languages be solved with dovetailing?

Tags: computability, undecidability

I'm a bit confused about the dovetailing concept. It seems too powerful. Could it solve non-recursively enumerable languages?

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"?

Comment: I mean can you use dovetailing to have some TM halt on accepted inputs for non-recursively enumerable languages?

Comment: Dovetailing is just a technique for programming Turing machines. It doesn't give Turing machines any additional power.

Comment: "to have some TM halt on accepted inputs". Basically,  dovetailing is simulation of TMs on some input. Thus, if a dovetailer simply simulates a TM $M$ on input $x$ to find out wether $M(x)$ eventually halts  and if $M(x)$ eventually halts then the dovetailer will eventually detect it. But it does not have a power of deciding whether or on $M(x)$ eventually halts.

Comment: In very concrete terms, dovetailing is usually exploited to execute many TMs concurrently, similarly to how an operating system runs multiple processes in a fair (starvation-free) way on a single CPU. You make a TM/process do a few steps, then you context-switch to another one, and so on. In this way, if some TM/process halts, you can detect that even if the other TM/processes are still running (and potentially loop forever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dovetailing is just a technique for programming Turing machines. It doesn't give Turing machines any additional power. In particular, dovetailing cannot cause a Turing machine to decide an undecidable problem, recognize an unrecognizable language, and so on.

While dovetailing might seem like an arcane technique, it is actually very similar to context-switching, which enables our computers to run many programs in parallel. This doesn't give our computers any more power – on the contrary, context-switching incurs overheads.